# A metric on the set of BV functions, is it mentioned/studied in literature?

Tags: real-analysis, fourier-analysis, harmonic-analysis

I'd like to propose the following metric which operates on the set $M$ of all square integrable functions that are also of bounded variation, of the form $f : (0,1) \to \mathbb{R}$.
Given any $x,y \in M$, $$d(x,y) = ||x-y||_{L^2} + |V_0^1(x) - V_0^1(y)|$$

Fourier series is not convergent in this metric! But if I use [this (not proven yet!) concept](https://mathoverflow.net/q/208867/14414), which is a slightly modified form of Fourier expansion, the resulting series converges in the above metric.

My question is, is this metric been studied anywhere in the literature, if so, what are the interesting properties/aspects of it. My hope is that, if this metric is interesting, then it would serve as a good motivation for [validating this concept.](https://mathoverflow.net/q/208867/14414)

Comment: Since the variation of a constant is zero, the variation itself is not a norm.  But you get a norm by adding something to take care of the one extra dimension.  You have chosen $\|f\|_2$, I have not seen it done this way.  I have seen $\|f\|_1$, I have seen $\|f\|_\infty$, and I have seen $|f(0)|$.  But of course all of these norms are "equivalent" (differ by at most a constant factor from each other).  Note bounded variation implies square-integrable.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : What I have described is a metric, not a norm! My intention is to define a metric, not a norm. you might have slipped into that assumption after seeing the first term, if i got it correctly.

Comment: agree on BV implies square integrability.

Comment: $d(x,y)$ has the form $\|x-y\|$ for a norm $\|f\| = \|f\|_2+V_0^1(f)$..

Comment: @GeraldEdgar : but look at second term, its different cannot be of the form of a norm. So what i am desribing is a metric. I have no intention to define a norm.

Comment: OK I see.  $|V_0^1(x)-V_0^1(y)|$ and not the usual $V_0^1(x-y)$.  In that case, no I have not seen this used.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar :  $|V_0^1(f) - V_0^1(g)| $ is not equal to $V_0^1(f-g)$

Comment: I believe what you're interested in, but for $||x-y||_{L^1}$ instead of $||x-y||_{L^2},$ can be found near the bottom of p. 422 of [*The space of functions of bounded variation and certain general spaces*](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1936-040-03/S0002-9947-1936-1501882-8/) by Clarence Raymond Adams [Trans. AMS 40 (1936), 421-438]. See also Abstract #1 [on p. 19 here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1937-43-01/S0002-9904-1937-06484-6/) (1937) and Abstract #1 [on p. 27 here](http://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1940-46-01/S0002-9904-1940-07145-9/) (1940).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Thanks for the reference, after reading that article, it seems to makes sense to keep $||.||_{L^1}$ instead of $||.||_{L^2}$, as we dont get any advantage goin from $||.||_{L^1}$ to $||.||_{L^2}$. thanks very much indeed, i could have never been able to search this reference.

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : There really is a good deal of work using this metric, in those papers.

Comment: @GeraldEdgar I do not see that BV implies square integrability. To the best of my knowledge one has the imbeddings $W^{1,1}(0,1)\hookrightarrow BV(0,1)\hookrightarrow L^1(0,1)$. Does $BV(0,1)$ imbeds in anything better than $L^1(0,1)$?

Comment: A BV function is, in particular, bounded.  Hence $L^\infty(0,1)$.

Comment: In dimension $n$ BV embeds into $L^{n/(n-1)}$.

Comment: If you're still interested in this topic, Chapter III of Hildebrandt's 1964 book **Introduction to the Theory of Integration** (reviewed [here](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.bams/1183526082)) has some material on bounded variation notions for functions of two real variables and specifically discusses Adams/Clarkson's formulation and Frechet's formulation. The book is in the Academic Press *Pure and Applied Mathematics* series, and thus can be found in most every U.S. university library (shelved at QA 3 .P8 location, I believe).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Do you suggest this reference for multivariable formulation of total variation? I tend to agree with the modern formulation of the TV for functions over $\mathbb{R}^N$ and no intensions to deviate. What I am interested in is the properties of the metric spaces that Adams discussions in your earlier reference, albeit for 1-d functions.

Comment: I simply mention this as a possibly more reader-friendly exposition of certain aspects of the topic that you might want to be aware of, even if you don't need it or are not personally interested, such as if someone asks you sometime where one might find in a treatment of this in a textbook. So this is more of a FYI comment to be filed away with your miscellaneous literature notes on the topic (or whatever system you use).

Comment: @DaveLRenfro : Thanks very much Dave. But I am still searching for it as I am from third world! Wonder shouldnt they put a ecopy of it on the internet as it is very old dating to 1964. I m hoping to find it in archive.org

Answer (score 3):

This is closely related to the so-called *metric of strict convergence* which is
$$
d(u,v) = \|u-v\|_{L^1} + |TV(u)-TV(v)|
$$
where $TV(u)$ denoted the total variation of $u$. This is indeed a metric on the space $BV(\Omega)$ (also for $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^n$). Hence, strict convergence of $u_n$ to $u$ is nothing else than saying
$$
u_n\to u\quad\text{in}\quad L^1,\quad\text{and}\quad TV(u_n)\to\ TV(u).
$$

Moreover, it has the nice property of meterizing the so-called *weak-$*$-convergence* in BV, which is defined as
$$
u_n\to u\quad\text{in}\quad L^1,\quad\text{and}\quad \int u_n\, \mathrm{div}\phi \to \int u\,\mathrm{div}\phi\quad\forall \phi\in C^1_0(\Omega).
$$
This is described, for example, in

> Ambrosio, Fusco, Pallara, *Functions of Bounded Variation and Free Discontinuity Problems*, Oxford University Press, 2000

and googling for something that contains "strict convergence" and something like "bounded variation" or "total variation" gives a lot of hits.

Comment: Hi Dirk, thanks for the answer and reference. This was pioneered by C Raymond Adams in his 1936 paper as mentioned by DaveLRenfro in the comments. I request you to add this to the answer. CA Raymonds also wrote a series of papers on this, where there is some general form for a linear functional on space $E$.

Comment: http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1940-048-01/S0002-9947-1940-0002017-4/S0002-9947-1940-0002017-4.pdf

Comment: This is 1940 paper which came later.

Comment: If the one-dimensional case is enough for you, you may well go with the Adams et al papers from the 30s. Nowadays there is well developed theory of BV spaces in any dimensions I personally like to read to newer more polished literature on the topic. You can, however, edit the post (which will then go the review cue). (On a different matter: I usually do not follow links that go directly to some pdf but would prefer a link to a site which states title/abstract and to on so that I can decide whether I not I would like to read the article.)

Comment: $$
d(u,v) = \|u-v\|_{L^1} + |TV(u)-TV(v)|
$$ What is more interesting is that the space BV(0,1), under this metric, is separable, uniformly bounded, compact and complete!